# Why in my test scala 2.11 faster than c++ qt 5.3?

Tags: c++, qt, scala

As I know c++ have very good performance. Scala haven't. And I write simple task. Create 100 Mb array, init it in a loop and write it to disk, 10 times.

Qt (5.3 clang) code:

```
QTime myTimer;
myTimer.start();

int size = 100*1024*1024;
for (int i = 0;i <= 10;i++)
{
    char *mem = new char[size];
    for(int j = 0;j <= size - 1;j++)
        mem[j] = j % 250;
    for(int j = size - 1;j >= 0;j--)
        mem[j] = j % 251;

    QFile file("/tmp/" + QString::number(i) + ".dat");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(mem, size);
    file.flush();
    file.close();

    qDebug() << i;
}

// do something..
int nMilliseconds = myTimer.elapsed();
qDebug() << nMilliseconds;
```

Scala (2.11) code:

```
var ms = System.currentTimeMillis
val size = 100*1024*1024
for (i <- 0 to 10){
  val mem = new Array[Byte](size)
  for(j <- 0 to size - 1)
    mem(j) = (j % 250).asInstanceOf[Byte]
  for(j <- size - 1 to 0)
    mem(j) = (j % 251).asInstanceOf[Byte]

  val file = new File("/tmp/" + i.toString + ".dat")
      using(new FileOutputStream(file)){
        stream =>
          stream.write(mem)
          stream.flush
      }

  println(i)
}

ms = System.currentTimeMillis - ms
println(ms)
```

MacBook Pro i7 8Gb 256 Gb SSD

Scala code: 5127 msec

Qt code:   10408 msec

Why scala approximately 2 times faster than c++ qt?

Comment: my initial thinking is that the Scala runtime is faster than the QT runtime, which most likely needs to initialize many more things than Scala

Comment: Is the C++ code compiled with optimization?

Comment: No, I wrote 2 unit tests (one in qt and one in scala) and simple ran one after another

Comment: I changed loop from 10 to 100 iterations. Results are the same: 110753 in qt vs 48064 in scala. It's not runtime initialization. Maybe code in qt have problems? Could you run this code on your Qt systems for comparison?

Comment: The QT documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html states that text is normally written to a file using http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html. I can imagine the standard write is suboptimal.

Comment: cageman, I have commented all file output and have received in 100 iterations: scala 21284 ms, qt 93511 ms. Please, could you run this qt code on your machines? We can compare results with my ultrabook.

Comment: Try doing it in raw C code and what times you get. That should tell you if the speed difference is due to QT or not. On my machine I get around 7 secs for 10 iterations outputting to a SSD drive. About half of that is pure file IO and half is the two `j` loops. I would also suggest trying it without the file output step.

Comment: uesp, what a hardware (proc, memory) do you have? And it's still worse than my scala running. I haven't big experience in c++, so I need help of community for understanding this situation.

Comment: Writing to a disk file, especially on a limited-endurance SSD drive, is a big source of uncertainty. Write to `/dev/null` on Unices, or `NUL` on Windows.

Comment: "As I know c++ have very good performance. Scala haven't." -> "You know nothing Jon Snow..."

Comment: In both cases, the explicit flush calls are completely superfluous - the implementation of the `using` function and of QFile  ensures that the file will be closed, and thus flushed, too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what's going on. You've tested a *debug* build of the C++ code. No wonder it's "slow".

Comment: Perhaps Scala can manage to deduce that the entire loop is overwritten in the second pass, and simply drops the first pass. I doubt it, but hey, who knows. This is easy to verify: simply reduce the initialization to a single pass, and ensure that your C++ code is compiled and run in release configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As I've suspected, you're measuring something that isn't there, or, rather, not what you *think* you're measuring.

To check what is the overhead of the *code* itself, you need to write to `/dev/null`, and you need to time the individual parts to see what really takes time. For the code below, here's the output I get:

```
initialization took 2666 ms
buffered QFile writes to /dev/null took 0 ms
unbuffered QFile writes to /dev/null took 0 ms
fwrites to /dev/null took 5 ms
buffered temporary QFile writes took 115 ms
unbuffered temporary QFile writes took 102 ms
fwrites to temporary file took 118 ms
```

This is consistent. Using the C library's `fwrite` is actually *slower* than using QFile on this particular platform. My temporary storage is fast, BTW.

Alas, this was on a **release** build. Let's see how it looks on a **debug** build:

```
initialization took 6524 ms
buffered QFile writes to /dev/null took 0 ms
unbuffered QFile writes to /dev/null took 0 ms
fwrites to /dev/null took 5 ms
buffered temporary QFile writes took 109 ms
unbuffered temporary QFile writes took 121 ms
fwrites to temporary file took 123 ms
```

**There is your slowdown**. You tested a **debug** build, and it was ~2x slower than what your hardware can do. JVM has ran the JIT on the hot path in the initialization. That's why the initialization in Scala performs on par with C++, as expected.

This is OS X 10.9.4, Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0, release build using Qt 5.3.1 on a 3.7GHz 3rd gen i7 CPU.

The benchmark code is below. Since `QFile` is a real C++ class and implements RAII properly, doing the explicit `flush()` and `close()` calls is pointless. The whole point of C++ is that you don't have to remember such silliness.

```
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QTemporaryFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cstdio>

QTextStream out(stdout);

template <typename F> void time(const char * task, F fun)
{
   QElapsedTimer timer;
   timer.start();
   int const N = 10;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) fun();
   out << task << " took " << timer.elapsed() << " ms" << endl;
}

QByteArray newData() {
   const int size = 100*1024*1024;
   QByteArray buf(size, Qt::Uninitialized);
   // CoW isn't free, using mem takes ~1/3 less time than using buf[x].
   char * const mem = buf.data();
   for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)
       mem[j] = j % 250;
   for (int j = size - 1;j >= 0; j--)
       mem[j] = j % 251;
   return buf;
}

void qFileWrite(const QByteArray & data, const char * name,
                QIODevice::OpenMode modeExtras = 0)
{
   QFile f(QString::fromLocal8Bit(name));
   if (! f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | modeExtras)) abort();
   if (f.write(data) != data.size()) abort();
}

void cWrite(const QByteArray & data, const char * name)
{
   std::FILE * f = fopen(name, "wb");
   if (!f) abort();
   if (fwrite(data.data(), 1, data.size(), f) != data.size()) abort();
   if (fclose(f) == EOF) abort();
}

QByteArray tempFileName() {
   QTemporaryFile f; f.setAutoRemove(false); if (!f.open()) abort();
   return f.fileName().toLocal8Bit();
}

int main()
{
   time("initialization", newData);
   QByteArray const data = newData();
   time("buffered QFile writes to /dev/null", [&]{
      qFileWrite(data, "/dev/null");
   });
   time("unbuffered QFile writes to /dev/null", [&]{
      qFileWrite(data, "/dev/null", QIODevice::Unbuffered);
   });
   time("fwrites to /dev/null", [&]{
      cWrite(data, "/dev/null");
   });
   time("buffered temporary QFile writes", [&]{
      qFileWrite(data, tempFileName());
   });
   time("unbuffered temporary QFile writes", [&]{
      qFileWrite(data, tempFileName(), QIODevice::Unbuffered);
   });
   time("fwrites to temporary file", [&]{
      cWrite(data, tempFileName());
   });
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kuba Ober, could you run your test without file IO, just memory allocation and assignment, and write your milliseconds here? For 10 and 100 iterations, of course. I'm not very good in Qt, so you can do measurements more accurately. And it's also very interesting to see results on another machine.

Comment: You've now tested things adequately to demonstrate what is (likely) going on, which now makes this a good answer.  I've removed my other comments.

Comment: @engineer The "just memory allocation and assignment" part is listed as "initialization" in the output. Did you want me to do something else? In any case, the file IO time is taken *completely* by the operating system moving the bits to the storage device - since, as you see, writing to `/dev/null` takes "zero" time. Pushing data to the OS is fast on modern hardware.

Comment: Kuba Ober, I have run your qt sources in release mode with 100 iterations and my result is 30160 ms. Scala's code with 100 iterations still less than qt: 26361ms. How is it possible?

Comment: This might be caused by the fact that  JVM handles memory differently than C++. Allocation of memory is faster in Java compared to C++ and total cost of deallocation (GC) is often smaller, too. Another reason might be that JVM just better optimizes those initialization loops than your C++ compiler. I've seen a few times modern Oracle JVM outsmarted gcc in loop optimization and many times just produced machine code with very similar performance. Times when JVM was 5-10x slower than native code are long over.